# What do I need to do to start working with Launchpad again on a new computer?

Tags: launchpad

I have followed the directions listed at http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/getting-set-up.html to get my desktop computer set up so that I could work on bug fixing during 12.04's development.

Now I am trying to get set up again on my laptop computer (different machine) so I can help contribute to [Ask Ubuntu badge integration with the Ubuntu Accomplishments system](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3282/18612). However, when I try to run the first command listed to do a `bzr branch`, I get the following error in my terminal:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
ConnectionReset reading response for 'BzrDir.open_2.1', retrying
Permission denied (publickey).
bzr: ERROR: Connection closed: Unexpected end of message. Please check connectivity and permissions, and report a bug if problems persist.
```

What do I need to do to get set up and ready to work again on a new machine? Should I just follow all the steps in the first link again (even though they seem to assume it's your first time getting set up with Launchpad)? Or are there steps I should skip / do differently?

*Note: I do not have access to my original desktop machine at this time.*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On your old machine, you generated a SSH key and then added that to your Launchpad account. Bzr uses that key to acces launchpad. So if the key on your new machine doesn't match the one you uploaded to Launchpad, you will be unable to branch code from certain repositories on Launchpad.

Two solutions are possible. The first is of course to transfer your SSH keys from the old machine. You'd need to bring over two files: .ssh/id_rsa and .ssh/id_rsa.pub. Watch the permissions, as SSH is very strict about that.

The second solution, if you have no access to your old machine BUT you can log into your Launchpad account, is to add a new SSH key so that Launchpad will let the new machine access bzr branches, since it will identify the new key as belonging to you.

For this, on the Getting Set Up document you posted, follow the steps for "[Create your SSH key](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/getting-set-up.html#create-your-ssh-key)" and "[Upload your SSH key to Launchpad](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/getting-set-up.html#upload-your-ssh-key-to-launchpad)".

This will at least allow you to run bzr branch without problems.

So in a nutshell:

1. Run `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
2. Open `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` using a text editor (gedit will do)
3. Copy the entire contents of the file (one very long line).
4. Open https://launchpad.net/~/+editsshkeys on your browser
5. Under "Add an SSH key", paste the line from step 3, then click on "Import Key".

Comment: Yep, everything started working as intended after that. Clear and informative answer; thank you very much!