# Agent admitted failure to sign using the key

Tags: ssh, launchpad, bazaar

After a fresh ubuntu install, it seems I can't use any `bzr branch` commands. I get the following error:

```
   Agent admitted failure to sign using the key. Permission denied
   (publickey). ConnectionReset reading response for 'BzrDir.open_2.1',
   retrying Agent admitted failure to sign using the key. Permission
   denied (publickey). bzr: ERROR: Connection closed: Unexpected end of
   message. Please check connectivity and permissions, and report a bug
   if problems persist.
```

I followed the steps provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144839/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-start-working-with-launchpad-again-on-a-new-computer) but without luck. Also, other solutions provided on the forum were not helpful.

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fix this error by loading your keys into your SSH agent with ssh-add:

Type `ssh-add` in your terminal, on the root folder where you want to clone the project.